# Sending a JSON request in the body and deserializing it to one of the abstract class's descendants

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

I'm trying to send a request to the server through the controller, where the request body is an object

Controller code :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<List<ExportResponseDto>> exportDataToOptimizer(@RequestBody ExportRequestDto exportRequestDto) {
        var request = exportService.createExportMainDto(exportRequestDto);
        var result = exportService.createRequestToMq(request);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Object code

```
@Data
@Builder
public class ExportRequestDto {
    private List<? extends DataExport> data;
}
```

When I send this request, I get the following error:

```
"JSON parse error: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class ru.rivc.crew.crewdata.optimizer.export.dto.dataexport.DataExport]: missing type id property '_class' (for POJO property 'data'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class ru.rivc.crew.crewdata.optimizer.export.dto.dataexport.DataExport]: missing type id property '_class' (for POJO property 'data')\n at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 11, column: 5] (through reference chain: ru.rivc.crew.crewdata.optimizer.export.dto.ExportRequestDto[\"data\"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])"
```

For the DataExport class itself, it seems that I set the annotations as needed:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonTypeInfo(use=JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property="_class")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = AirportExport.class, name = "AirportExport"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TimeTableExport.class, name = "TimeTableExport")}
)
public abstract class DataExport {

    private DataType dataType;

}
```

Descendant class code from DataExport

```
 @Getter
@Setter
public class AirportExport extends DataExport {

}
```

Another class similar

I don’t understand how to set it up so that Jackson himself determines which class to convert the object to
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you read the exception message? It says - `missing type id property '_class'`, meaning the json you send does not contain the property jackson needs to resolve the exact type. Other than that, your setup for jackson is correct.

Comment: I set the @JsonTypeName("AirportExport") annotation on each class, but that didn't help.
I'm trying to send this JSON
{
  "data": [
    {
      "dataType": "AIRPORTS",
      "_class": "AirportExport"
    }
  ]
}
But I am getting an error
 Could not resolve type id 'AirportExport' as a subtype of `ru.rivc.crew.crewdata.optimizer.export.dto.dataexport.DataExport`: no such class found; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve type id 'AirportExport' as a subtype of `ru.rivc.crew.crewdata.optimizer.export.dto.dataexport.DataExport`